# Bing maps two-way binding to Center property. Animation problem

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, animation, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

There is an example of two-way binding to Center property from Micrsoft guys.
You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.DataBinding.TutorialViewBindingTwoWay).

Its sample works fine, but they disabled full animation. When I set `AnimationLevel="Full"` and use the Compass I get trembling picture.

I really like aminations effects and don't want to turn it off.

Are there any ways to get working Compass and keep full animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem and as far as i know, it hasn't been fixed. I too would very much like it to be fixed.

When full animation is on and the map is moved, it will move the map in an arch (zooms out and then back in). However, small distance movements still use the arch and this creates the shaking.

I have searched extensively (4 months ago) for a good work around for this  problem.
I didn't find anything other than turning off the full animation.